# Angular 4 Animation Screen Rotation

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am trying to achieve **Screen Rotation Animation in Angular 4** on Route change same as in this [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/bnyJ6/1/). This plunker is written with Angular 1

Will be very thankful if some one can take up this. On Route change I want to achieve this screen flip effect.

```
<style ng-bind-html-unsafe="style"></style>

<div class="cube container">
    <div ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"></div>
</div>
/*style binding */
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="masthead">
            <h1 class="muted">PAGE 1</h1>

            <button class="btn display-button" ng-click="direction('front');go('/two')">Go Page 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
/*style binding */
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="masthead">
            <h1 class="muted">PAGE 1</h1>
            <button class="btn display-button" ng-click="direction('back');go('/one')">Go page 1</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? _"Will be very thankful if some one can take up this."_ What does this mean? What is this code? Doesn't it work? Why not?

Comment: not my problem if you can't understand what's the meaning of "Will be very thankful if some one can take up this"